# Where does “about:blank” and other similar keywords come from, and why are they needed?

Tags: browser, url, uri

I know `about:Tabs` goes to the New Tab page, and `about:blank` goes to a predictably blank page.

But how and why did this function come about? And are there other keywords that come after `about:` with different functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `about:` is a URI scheme. As explained here on the Wikipedia page on the [about URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About_URI_scheme):

> **about** is an internal URI scheme (also known as a "URL scheme" or, erroneously, "protocol") implemented in various Web browsers to reveal internal state and built-in functions. It is an IANA officially registered scheme, and is standardized.

So this is basically an internal web browser URI that is reserved for doing specific things within a web browser. What things? As the official [IANA (Internet Assigned Numbers Authority) web site](https://www.iana.org/assignments/about-uri-tokens/about-uri-tokens.xhtml), on a basic level it’s stuff like this:

- **about:blank**: The `about:blank` URI references a blank page.
- **about:invalid**: The `about:invalid` URI references a non-existent document with a generic error condition. It can be used when a URI is necessary, but the default value shouldn't be resolveable as any type of document.
- **about:srcdoc**: Used as the document's address of iframe srcdoc documents in HTML.
- **about:legacy-compat**: For use in DOCTYPEs in HTML documents when needed for compatibility with XML tools.
- **about:html-kind**: The `about:html-kind` URI identifies the vocabulary of kind values in HTML specifications from W3C and WhatWG.

That said, what I listed above are just the bare basics: Look at [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About_URI_scheme) again to find browser specific `about:` URI schemes.

Comment: about:robots in Firefox is a good one.